# Database left outer join to with Same table with optimal performance

Tags: sql, database, join, left-join

I have a status table A with Code & its description related to a particular name.

```
Code   Desc       Name
 01    INITIAL   STATUS_A
 02    SUCCESS   STATUS_A
 03    FAILED    STATUS_A
 04    FAILED    STATUS_B
 05    RETRY     STATUS_C
 06    SUCESS    STATUS_D
```

and so on...
Now I have a table B as master record with code associate from Table A.

```
ID  column1 column2 column3 statusA statusB statusC statusD 
432   XXXX   YYYY    ZZZZ      03     04      05      06
```

Now I need to form a query to get output data with code description from table A.

I have done this using left outer join. Can someone suggest a better solution.

*Left Outer Join Query*

`Select b.column1 ,b.column2,
a1.Desc as Status_A_Desc ,
a2.Desc as Status_B_Desc,
a3.Desc as Status_C_Desc,
a4.Desc as Status_D_Desc
from B b left outer join 
A a1 on a1.code = b.statusA and a1.Name ='STATUS_A'
left outer join 
A a2 on a2.code = b.statusB and a2.Name ='STATUS_B'
left outer join 
A a3 on a3.code = b.statusC and a3.Name ='STATUS_C'
left outer join 
A a4 on a4.code = b.statusD and a4.Name ='STATUS_D'
where b.ID = 432`

Comment: This kind of repeating column pattern usually suggests a missing child table... What happens when you need Status_E? Your code is broken!

Comment: Actually the system is already in place and there are only 4 fixed status column in master table B.I was looking for some effective to re write the outer join query that i have formed

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select a.code,
       max(case when a.name = 'Status_A' then a.desc end) as a,
       max(case when a.name = 'Status_B' then a.desc end) as b,
       max(case when a.name = 'Status_C' then a.desc end) as c,
       max(case when a.name = 'Status_D' then a.desc end) as d
from a
group by a.code;
```

Depending on your database, the joins might be better.  This has the advantage that you can add as many fields as you like with basically the same performance.